# Date not inserted in salesforce using wordpress plugin - gravity forms salesforce

Tags: wordpress, salesforce

I am getting an error when i submit the form saying that the date is not a valid type.
As a result, the entry is not being added into salesforce.
I am based in India.

```
Errors when adding to Salesforce: Message: '2013-05-01 13:03:13' is not a valid value for the type xsd:dateTime Faultstring: '2013-05-01 13:03:13' is not a valid value for the type xsd:dateTime File: /nfs/c04/h03/mnt/163576/domains/removedurl.com/html/wp-content/plugins/gravity-forms-salesforce/developerforce/include/SforceBaseClient.php Line: 494 Args: a:3:{s:8:"LastName";s:21:"techietonya@gmail.com";s:5:"Email";s:21:"redacted";s:11:"CreatedDate";s:19:"2013-05-01 13:03:13";} Trace: a:16:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:"file";s:138:"/nfs/c04/h03/mnt/163576/domains/removedurl.com/html/wp-content/plugins/gravity-forms
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks